# How to move collection view cell & rearrange them in iOS when collection view in long press mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uicollectionview

I have created a `UICollectionView` view in which i am giving effects like spring board of iOS. When i long press my `UICollectionView` then they start animating & it works fine. Now when i have long pressed the cell & animation is started then i want to move the cells on diffrent position & keep it there until next time i change it. Please tell me how i can do this?

Here's my code for animation of cell

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }
    p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collection_view];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collection_view indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
    }
    else {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"longPressed"];
        [self.collection_view reloadData];

    } 
}
```

**CellForItem**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"arr_album index row");
    BlogAlbumCell  *cell;
    static NSString *identifier = @"UserBlogAlbum";
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UserAlbum *user_allbum=[arr_userAlbums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.label_blog_name.text=user_allbum.album_name;
    cell.image_blog_image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"];
    [cell.image_blog_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_allbum.album_image]]];
    if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"longPressed"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
        [anim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
        [anim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI/50]];
        [anim setDuration:0.1];
        [anim setRepeatCount:NSUIntegerMax];
        [anim setAutoreverses:YES];
        cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        [cell.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"SpringboardShake"];
        CGFloat delButtonSize = 20;

        UIButton *delButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, delButtonSize, delButtonSize)];
        delButton.center = CGPointMake(9, 10);
        delButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [delButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_30.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:delButton];
        [delButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteRecipe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"singleTap"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    { 
        for(UIView *subview in [cell subviews])
        {
            if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
            }
            else
            {
                // Do nothing - not a UIButton or subclass instance
            }
        }
        [cell.layer removeAllAnimations];
        // _deleteButton.hidden = YES; 
        // [_deleteButton removeFromSuperview];
    }
        return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this drag and drop collectionview project.
https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: Your example is only for iPad but i need on both.

Comment: it's for iPhone as well

Comment: I don't want to use it

Comment: You don't have to use it, you can do what ever you want :)
I would take a look on how he implemented the long press move and do the same... Just saying.

Comment: I want to long press for both shaking of icons & moving as well.Making custom an existed library would be big headache so it's i would better write my code.